# History of deletion-contraction formula

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, spanning-tree

The following is known as *deletion-contraction formula*:

> Assume $\Gamma$ is a connectted graph with edge $\rho$ then
>   $$t(\Gamma)=t(\Gamma\backslash\rho)+t(\Gamma/\rho),$$
>   where $\Gamma\backslash\rho$ is $\Gamma$ with the edge $\rho$ removed and $\Gamma/\rho$ obtained from $\Gamma$ by contracting $\rho$ and $t(\Gamma)$ is the number of spanning trees in $\Gamma$.

The statement appear as Proposition 4.9 in Graph Theory by Bondy
Murty with no reference. ([Haghighi and Bibak](http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-password-2009/ams-password45-48-2009/shirdarehAMS45-48-2009.pdf) claim that it is due to Kirchhoff, but I was not able to find the statement  [in his paper on the subject](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k15157m/f515.image))

I wonder who made this observation first, or at least what is the earlies reference to this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to have first been observed in

*Brooks, R.L.; Smith, C.A.B.; Stone, A.H.; Tutte, W.T.*, [**The dissection of rectangles into squares**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-40-00718-9), Duke Math. J. 7, 312-340 (1940). [ZBL0024.16501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0024.16501).

See equation 3.12 and Theorem 3.13 in the paper. I found a discussion of this in a survey paper of Tutte:

*Tutte, W.T.*, [**Graph-polynomials**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0196-8858(03)00041-1), Adv. Appl. Math. 32, No. 1-2, 5-9 (2004). [ZBL1041.05001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1041.05001).

Tutte indicates in this paper that these coauthors discovered the deletion-contraction relation for spanning trees. The similarity with the deletion-contraction relation for the chromatic polynomial then led Tutte to define the two variable Tutte polynomial. So this seems to pin down the origin of this formula.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly a reference, but I found some discussion of this formula in Bill Tutte's graph-theoretic memoirs, *Graph Theory as I Have Known it* (Oxford, 1998). In Chapter 5 ("Algebra in Graph Theory"), he writes:

> In their study of complexities or tree-numbers the Four made much use of the recursion formula
> $$C(G) = C(G'_A) + C(G''_A)$$
> When I was doing my PhD research I began to collect other functions of graphs that satisfied similar recursions. [(p.53)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uYW2tttqQ74C&lpg=PA53&dq=%22the%20Four%20made%20much%20use%20of%20the%20recursion%20formula%22&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q=%22the%20Four%20made%20much%20use%20of%20the%20recursion%20formula%22&f=false)

The "Four" that Tutte is referring to here are: [R. L. Brooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._Leonard_Brooks), [C. A. B. Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedric_Smith_(statistician)), [A. H. Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Harold_Stone), and [W. T. Tutte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._T._Tutte). (He mentions that they all met as students at Cambridge in the [Trinity Mathematical Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Mathematical_Society).) So perhaps this deletion-contraction formula was folklore at the time, or at least "Fourlore".

I think that the connection to [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) is indirect, corresponding to the fact that the "complexity" and the "tree-number" of a graph coincide. Tutte explains in Chapter 1 ("Squaring the square"):

> We learned that Kirchhoff's Laws for a network $N$ were associated with a special matrix $K(N)$ called, by us at least, the Kirchhoff matrix of $N$. [...] We learned that the determinant of the matrix $K_i(N)$ obtained from $K(N)$ by striking out the $i$th row and column was independent of $i$. We decided to call its value the "complexity" $C(N)$ of $N$. [(p.7)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oCQ0yQSWhikC&lpg=PA7&dq=%22We%20learned%20that%20Kirchhoff%27s%20Laws%20for%20a%20network%22&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q=%22We%20learned%20that%20Kirchhoff%27s%20Laws%20for%20a%20network%22&f=false)
>
> [...]
>
> By expanding a determinant it can be shown that the number of spanning trees of $G$ is the complexity $C(G)$ of $G$. For a general electrical network $N$ the complexity $C(N)$ proves to be the sum over all the spanning trees of $N$ of the products of the conductances of their edges. This result is known as the Matrix-Tree Theorem, and it goes back to Kirchhoff. [(p.11)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uYW2tttqQ74C&lpg=PA11&ots=VcMW6j-gdv&dq=%22By%20expanding%20a%20determinant%20it%20can%20be%20shown%20that%20the%20number%20of%20spanning%20trees%22&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q=%22By%20expanding%20a%20determinant%20it%20can%20be%20shown%20that%20the%20number%20of%20spanning%20trees%22&f=false)

Comment: Posted this answer before seeing that Ian Agol found an explicit reference! I will leave it up though, for the links to the historical discussion by Tutte.

Comment: This looks similar to the discussion in the "graph-polynomials" paper I linked to.